# Order of custom posts in custom Wordpress query not as expected

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I have a custom Wordpress query which looks like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'publication',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'my-category',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'publication_year',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$loop1 = new WP_Query($args);
```

I am querying a custom post type, wanting only the posts with a certain category. FWIW, I created the post type using PODS. The query works properly with one little exeption - the `order` clause:

The `orderby` field refers to a `date` field named "publication_year" which only shows the year values 2015, 2014, 2013 etc., but in the database contains full dates like "2013-01-18" and similar.

Now, the order which I get with the above query is 2013, 2014, 2015 - although `order` is `DESC`, for which I would expect the opposite. If I change it to `ASC`, I get 2015, 2014, 2013!

I don't understand that - I would expect ascending order to be 2013, 2014, 2015 etc. Where am I wrong?

Comment: for some unknown reason SO won't let me add the "wp-query" tag to this question... (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publication_year` is not a column in the `wp_posts` table. See the [WordPress Database Description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). If the `orderby` parameter is not valid, WordPress will fall back to the default sorting which is the `post_date` column.

If it is a meta value you should use:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'publication',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'my-category',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'publication_year',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

See the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for more information.